# powershell hash building from an array

Tags: powershell, perl, hash

title: powershell forloop with array and hash?

I know how to do this in perl and unixshell. I don't see it in powershell.  So I will ask.

I will keep my question simple.
if I have a list, I would like to make a hash where the keys are the elements of the list, and the value is a property.

Like I have an array of 7 dwarves servers

```
$d = ( "happy", "sleepy", "sneezy", "doc", "grumpy", "dopey", "bashful" )
```

And I would want to hash to be their height in inches: `d_height{ "happy" } = "40"`

Seems kind of simple?  Ok.  But if the list is made on the fly, so the hash has to be made on the fly. How?

.... more detail if you want it.....
I start with powershell, then revert to perl because I know THAT.

I have an array of 7 dwarves servers

```
$d = ( "happy", "sleepy", "sneezy", "doc", "grumpy", "dopey", "bashful" )

foreach ( $one ( 0 .. ( $d.count - 1 ))){
   $d[ $one ]
}
```

OK.. fine.  Now I want the boottime.
I already know the command. So just pretend this is it.

```
$boottime = server.blahblah
```

Now I revert to perl because I know it. (sigh)

```
foreach ( @d ){
   $boottime =  $d[ $one ].blahblah ;
   if ( $boottime =~ "AM $" or $boottime =~ "PM $" ){
       $d_height{ $d } = $boottime;
   }
       $d_height{ $d } = "unknown";
}
```

Now that I'm already with busted code, here is the rest. I went to perl.

```
foreach $x ( keys( %d_height )){
   printf("%-20s %03d", $x, $d_height{ $x } );
}
```

I know.... format table with `@{ hash stuff }` yeah... fine.
but that's perl....

how could I do this in powershell?

Comment: The height of a dwarf equals a server's boot time? What?

Comment: I have a list @A.  I want a hash where the keys of the hash are @A.
I can explain if I hardwire everything like so:
    `@A = ("1","2","3") $H{"1"}="apples"  $H{"2"}="unset"  $H{"3"}="tomato"`
Instead of hardwiring, I will have @A built on the fly from some powershell command.
I want to have the keys of %H hash built on the fly. (my question).
So how do I on the fly build %H hash with the keys of %H being @A?

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is easier to write than the question.   And I think this should not be in serverfault.  It should be in the programming section.  oh. here is the answer.

```
$A = ("one","two","three")
PS:C:\> foreach( $one in ( $A)){
>> $one
>> }
>>
one
two
three
PS:C:\>
PS:C:\>$B=@{}
PS:C:\>foreach ( $one in  $A ){
>> $B.$one = "preset"
>> }
>>
PS C:\> $B

Name                           Value
----                           -----
two                            preset
three                          preset
one                            preset
```

That's it.  I should have never mentioned Dwarfs except for humor.

Comment: And the question should have been:
I can make an array of values.
I can update a value of a hash.
but I want a hash where the keys are built from the array values.

Comment: so, you have 2 arrays of equal lengths, and you want to combine/zip them into a hashtable?

Comment: no.  I was keeping it simple.  VERY simple.  I have one array.  I was trying to make a hash where the keys of the new hash are built from the array.  I could add more text, but the more I talk, the more convoluted it got.